# Cannot suppress Stanford parser warnings

Tags: stanford-nlp

While using the TokenizerFacotry of Stanford parser I made sure to set options as "untokenizable=noneDelete" still I could not manage to get ride of warnings, what could be the problem?

```
public static List<Tree> findHeadNounPhrases(List<String> unites)
{
    List<Tree> nps = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    for(String sentence : unites)
    {

        HeadFinder hf = new PennTreebankLanguagePack().headFinder();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(sentence);
         TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory =
                PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "untokenizable=noneDelete");
        tokenizerFactory.setOptions("untokenizable=noneDelete");
        Tokenizer<CoreLabel> tok =tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(reader);
        List<CoreLabel> rawWords2 = tok.tokenize();
        Tree tree = lp.apply(rawWords2);
        ...
}
```

I am getting the following warnings:

```
Mar 10, 2016 11:13:51 AM edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer next
WARNING: Untokenizable: ି (U+B3F, decimal: 2879)
Mar 10, 2016 11:13:51 AM edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer next
WARNING: Untokenizable: ି (U+B3F, decimal: 2879)
Mar 10, 2016 11:13:56 AM edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer next
WARNING: Untokenizable:  (U+89, decimal: 137)
```

Comment: Could you list out what warnings you are getting?

Comment: WARNING: Untokenizable: ି (U+B3F, decimal: 2879)

Comment: I am getting this exact error too, and I am using the latest Git pull master version.

Comment: I also want to add that this is not just a warning. This causes the CoreNLP server to return HTTP Error 400 instead of the expected parsed JSON

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I just edited my CoreNLP server code to set the default to what I desire (allDelete in my case). I suggest you to dig into the code and see the place where it generates the error. If the error is so disturbing to you then you can comment it out and re-compile all with ant.